Is it posibble to export multiple armatures in a .GLB/GLTF file?
So I have a rigged arms model, and a rigged gun model. I've tried parenting the root bone of the gun rig to the hand controller bone of the arms rig. This worked well in blender, but when exporting the model, it seems like the connection between the gun and the arms model doesn't work(the arms have gone into resting position and wiggle when the animation is played, but the gun doesn't animate(I've viewed the file using Preview, and Godot 4.). If I can't export 2 armatures together, what should I do then? Exporting the gun and arms separately maybe, or joining the armatures(I have tried this, but gave up since all my bones had gone crazy).Removing the gun rig fixes the issues, but now the gun isn't animated anymore.



To me it would make sense to include all of the animations in one Armature, with bones for the arms and gun included. I'm less familiar with Godot, more with Unreal, but I would do it that way personally. You might have to redo some of your anims, or re-parent things correctly, but thats the name of the game when you're dealing with rigging. Sometimes you do things a total wrong way and only realize later on you should've done it different, and there's no other option but to redo alot of it. I've been there many times. Live and learn.

It may still be possible to export multiple armatures in this file format; I'm not sure. I think your question is really more like "Will {target game engine} accept animated models with multiple armatures?" to which I'm inclined to believe the answer is no.

@Jakemoyo How can I join the armatures whilst keeping the bones in place? Alternatively, I could probably just add some bones to the arms rig and use those instead.
